# Target checkbox inside a table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with one row and three columns, on the third column I have a checkbox that I want to react if theres a change:

```
<table id="tabla_busqueda">
   <tr>
     <td>Data 1</td>
     <td>Data 2</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_nuevo"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried:

```
$('table tr td input.check_nuevo').on('change', function(){
    alert('hello');
});

$('table#tabla_busqueda .check_nuevo').on('change', function(){}
$('table td .check_nuevo').on('change', function(){}
```

and some others, but nothing seems to work. What am i doing wrong? Any suggestions on how to target that checkbox?

this is the code in php that generates my table

```
foreach ($datos as $row) {
                $clase = ($fila % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
                $resultado .=   '<tr class="'. $clase .'"> 
                                    <td class="imagen_chica" ><img src="' . base_url() . 'product_images_mini/' . $row->image_path . '"></td>
                                    <td>' . $row->titulo . '<em> de </em>' . $row->nombre_autor . '</td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_nuevo"></td>
                                </tr>'; 
                                $fila++;    
                }
```

Comment: The first one looks fine. The others are not syntactically valid JS.

Comment: but the first one is working for me

Comment: They all look fine to me (if you close the latter two properly). Did you remember document.ready ?

Comment: I guess the OP wants to catch the event when he sets the value programmatically. Is that correct? For a user action, your code should work.

Comment: It seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/KCYmd/1/

Comment: i know it should work, but it doesnt,. one thing i did not mention b/c i think is irrelevant is that im generating the table content in php and sending it as a string to populate the table, is this relevant for it to not be working??, the table displays completely fine, its just the checkbox that doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you're binding the change handlers, the content isn't there yet. Something like this should work:

```
$(document).on('change', 'table tr td input.check_nuevo', function() {
    alert("Is this working now?");
});
```

Comment: yes it does, my bad not mentioning thate table was added on a click event, im kinda new to jquery, thanks again, it works perfect

Answer (score -2):

Use 'bind' instead of 'on':

```
$('table tr td input.check_nuevo').bind('change', function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Check this jsfiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/5cJjh/

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem. `on` should work as well